# Yii2 formatter language

Tags: yii2, formatter

This is my configurations:

```
'formatter' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            'dateFormat' => 'd MMMM Y',
            'locale' => 'ru-RU'

      ],
```

When I am trying this:

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('2014-01-01');
```

I get:

```
01 Jan 2014
```

But I want the same in Russian.

**Solved:**

Open the file php.ini via OpenServer and uncomment `;extension=php_intl.dll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the config you specified should output `01 янв. 2014`
you are most likely missing [php-intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension

Answer (score 0):

With formatter set to `'dateFormat' => 'php:d M Y'` you can only get 01 Jan 2014 because PHP's date `M` stands for

> A short textual representation of a month, three letters: `Jan` through `Dec`

If you want date to be formatted by intl for your language you need to set formatter with ICU:

```
'dateFormat' => 'd MMM Y'
```

like described at [ICU User Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

Comment: I've edited my question. It doesn't work, too. I was trying this: uncomment `;extension=php_intl.dll`, but after reloading OpenServer it returns to comment. I don't understand how to change it with administration rules

Comment: @Bizley yii2 does [internal conversion](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/af71e0fca0b8cc7ea11ce18824d3e9a7af6866ef/framework/i18n/Formatter.php#L631) to icu formats regardless

Comment: @csminb good to know, so it must be missing intl like you said.

Comment: How to uncomment this extension?

Comment: Okey, I've found how to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, anyway :)